# Symfony one to many dql query

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-many, dql

I am creating symfony web app and have problem with making appropiate dql query for inbox.
This is code of entity causing problems:

```
class Message
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="fromUser", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $fromUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $fromEmail;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="toUser", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $toUser;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",length=255)
 */
protected $subject;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
 */
protected $date;



/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $toEmail;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $content;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $sent;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $spammed;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="View")
 * @JoinTable(name="messages_views",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="message_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="view_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
protected $view;



class View extends CollectionType

{
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->trashed = false;
    $this->deleted = false;
    $this->seen = false;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $trashed;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $deleted;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $seen;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
}
```

$view is class ArrayCollection() and one to many relationship.
And i want to choose field "where $toUser = :me" and which contains $view where $view->user = :me and $view->trashed = false" (in case if there are two $view's (not possible/expected ) choose first found)
Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit: 
at the moment i have something like this

```
  $get = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT m
            FROM MonoAdminBundle:Message m
            WHERE m.userTo = :me AND m.sent = true 
            AND 
            ORDER BY m.date DESC
        ')
        ->setParameter('me', $me->getId())->getArrayResult();
    $ret = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($get as $message) {
        if ($message->getSpammed() === false) {
            foreach ($message->getView() as $view) {
                if ($view->getUser() == $me) {
                    if ($view->getTrashed() === false) {
                        $ret->add($message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But it is not good idea as i want to use paginator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a queryBuilder.

```
$qb = $entityManager->getRepository(Message::class)->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb->addWhere('m.toUser = :me')
   ->innerJoin('m.view', v)
   ->addWhere('v.user = :me')
   ->addWhere('v.trashed = :isTrashed')
   ->setParameter('me', $user)
   ->setParameter('isTrashed', false);
```

To get DQL:

```
$qb->getQuery()->getDQL();
```

Then get results:

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResults();
```